# How to work with LumiaImagingSDK.UWP 3.0 in windows 10 mobile app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, lumia-imaging-sdk

I work with app for windows 10. I tried to make an application for image editing.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(ImageUrl);
var source = new StreamImageSource(stream);
var info = await source.GetInfoAsync();
```

and I get an error in line `var source = new StreamImageSource(stream);`:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Lumia.Imaging.Managed.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> RenderImage error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

What am I doing wrong?
I Work with LumiaImagingSDK.UWP 3.0.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem, can you please provide more details? I suppose that you are getting a image from url on internet, then what you want to do?

Comment: Yes. I getting a image from url on internet.

Comment: Then what are you want to do with this image using ImageingSDK?

Comment: i want create blurred image control.

Answer (score 0):

The formats supported by the StreamImageSource ctor of the Imaging SDK are :
 Jpeg
 Png
 Gif
 Bmp
 Wbmp
 Tiff

Check that your URL is correct and points to one of these images formats.

Comment: i missing sdk version in my issue. I work with LumiaImagingSDK.UWP 3.0. In v2.0 work fine. How to work with LumiaImagingSDK.UWP 3.0 with image from url?  I use Jpeg format.

Answer (score 0):

As we've discussed in the comment, you want to blur image, and there is built-in [BlurEffect Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.adjustments.blureffect.aspx) in the LumiaImagingSDK.UWP 3.0, I used this effect to wrote a demo here:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="originalimg" Grid.Column="0" />
        <SwapChainPanel x:Name="SwapChainPanelTarget" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("xxxx(uri address)");
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                string filename = "test.jpg";
                var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await response.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(stream);
                }
                StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);

                //show original image in the Image control
                IRandomAccessStream inputStream1 = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(inputStream1);
                originalimg.Source = bitmap;

                //use the blureffect
                IRandomAccessStream inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                BlurEffect blureffect = new BlurEffect();
                inputStream.Seek(0);
                blureffect.Source = new Lumia.Imaging.RandomAccessStreamImageSource(inputStream);
                var render = new SwapChainPanelRenderer(blureffect, SwapChainPanelTarget);
                await render.RenderAsync();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I stored the image each time in the local folder, and I used [Windows.Web.Http namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Web.Http);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), not [System.Net.Http Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Http);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). Since I can't reproduce your problem, to save the image to file and read the file stream here can work.